# Pandas usecols all except last

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file, is it possible to have `usecols` take all columns except the last one when utilizing `read_csv` without listing every column needed.

For example, if I have a 13 column file, I can do `usecols=[0,1,...,10,11]`. Doing `usecols=[:-1]` will give me syntax error?

Is there another alternative? I'm using `pandas 0.17`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just read a single line using [`nrows=1`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) to get the cols and then re-read in the full csv skipping the last col by slicing the column array from the first read:

```
cols = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=1).columns
df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=cols[:-1])
```

Answer (score 18):

Starting from version `0.20` the `usecols` method in pandas accepts a callable filter, i.e. a `lambda` expression. Hence if you know the name of the column you want to skip you can do as follows:

```
columns_to_skip = ['foo','bar']
df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=lambda x: x not in columns_to_skip )
```

Here's the documentation [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#filtering-columns-usecols).