# How to do array slicing with a python sequence

Tags: python, slice

I am using `numpy.genfromtxt` and the `usecols` parameter allows filtering out columns (by non-inclusion).  For a lengthy list of columns it is not ideal to explicitly mention every single one - given that only *one* column need not be included.

If the *sequence* were instead a *list* then we could use

```
  usecols=[1:]
```

However that is not possible for a sequence - which afaict needs to be like

```
 usecols=(1,2,3,4, .. and many many more ..)
```

Here is the specific invocation that is being attempted:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',',skip_header= 1,usecols=[1:])
```

That does not compile due to the invalid attempt to use the slicing syntax on the sequence.   is there any alternative supported by sequences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas usecols all except last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424503/pandas-usecols-all-except-last)

Comment: maybe - but the answer given below was not included there and it's useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the complete column list with something like `[i for i in range(n)]` and then remove the desired element with `remove()` and pass this filtered list to the `usecols`.

Comment: that's helpful:  can you please add this specific code to your answer  `indats = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',',skip_header= 1,usecols=(x for i,x in enumerate(range(18)) if i!=0))`

Comment: No need for a list comprehension. `range` already does what you want: `usecols=tuple(range(1,18))`

Comment: Also, for future reference, there's no point using `enumerate` on a one-argument `range` - `i` and `x`will always be the same.

Comment: @Tomothy32 I am basically unfamiliar with python sequences and their relation to .. well .. anything..   Just learnt they appear to be interchangeable with tuples