# Pandas how to read_excel x to last column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read an xlsx file into a datafram. I do not want to read the first two columns. Furthermore, I do not want to specify the last column that should be read, because additional columns will be added in the future to the xlsx file.

I tried the following:

`pd.read_excel("Securities Input from depo.xlsx", sheet_name = 1, header = 5, usecols = [2:])`

But that does not work due to invalid syntax.

Is it possible to read the third to last column with pd.read_excel? If yes, what would be the correct syntax?

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas usecols all except last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424503/pandas-usecols-all-except-last)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got thorough pandas documentation, unfortunately they dont accept "usecolns" value that you were expecting.
Here is the alternate to your problem. (ps: first answer on stack Overflow, apologies)

```
df = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")
for index, heading in enumerate(df):
if index >= 2:
    print("do something")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I will just read the whole file and than drop the n/a columns or first columns which will have the same result as not reading these columns in the first place.